# String exectuion without a function

Tags: php, security

One of my website was hacked, during the cleanup process I found a few files with some cryptic code. Doing a bit of research I found that a piece of string was getting executed without being passed to a function. I am a bit stumped as to how PHP is executing that string? Does PHP automatically `eval` strings?

Here's a piece of the string I found `$VCAzeJzvMaKiJXvfeJZd='99V38=jVN4C;.Z<'^'ZK3RLX50;Z OG5R';` when I add it to a test script as below it produces `create_function`:

```
<?php

echo $VCAzeJzvMaKiJXvfeJZd='99V38=jVN4C;.Z<'^'ZK3RLX50;Z OG5R';

// output : create_function
```

P.S: in the malicious file I found, there's no `echo`, just a long cryptic string. I added `echo` in the code above for test purpose.

Comment: No strings  don't automagically get eval'ed, in this case it's actually 2 strings, being bitwise Xor'd. Note the `^` between the 2 strings.

Comment: After the value of `$VCAzeJzvMaKiJXvfeJZd` is set to the string `'create_function'` there is probably somewhere a `$VCAzeJzvMaKiJXvfeJZd([...])` call - that will invoke `create_function`. No magic eval, just normal php behavior.

Comment: @JonStirling thank you for the info, I'll dig a bit more around this.

Comment: @thehennyy totally agree with the no magic eval. :) Since it was a long string I had a sneaking suspicion that somewhere down the line the `create_function` is being called. My dilemma was how was PHP executing the string without the string being passed to another function like `eval`, now that Jon Stirling pointed it out that it's an Xor operation,it all make sense.

Comment: @JonStirling please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, strings don't automagically get eval'ed, in this case it's actually 2 strings being bitwise Xor'd. Note the `^` between the 2 strings.